# Can some probability triple give rise to any probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and random variable $X:\Omega\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ with $\mathcal{B}$ denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then, the distribution function of $X$ can be defined as
$$
F(x)=P(\{w\in\Omega:X(w)\leq x\})\tag{$*$}.
$$
Clearly, the RHS of ($*$) depends on $\Omega$, $P$, and the function $X$ whereas the LHS doesn't have to share such dependence. For example, we can define the LHS as the normal CDF $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-s^2/2)ds$. So I have two related questions:

1. Given $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, how do we then know all the possible $F(\cdot)$'s that can be induced by appropriately defined random variables i.e. measurable functions from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$?
2. Is there some $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that for *any* CDF $F(\cdot)$, there is some random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ such that the distribution of $X$ is $F$?

If the questions are unclear, I'll be happy to edit / clarify. I would also appreciate it if you could include some references in your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem. A place to start with question 2: how many CDFs are there? The answer is $\beth_1$, i.e. the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Here's my proof (it has some details to be filled). How do you construct a CDF? First you choose some countable number of points to be discontinuities. Then you choose numbers in $[0,1]$ for the size of the jumps. Then you choose continuous functions on each of the subintervals.

Comment: So because a countable union of countable sets is countable, you are dealing with essentially $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \times C([0,1])^{\mathbb{N}}$. By a couple basic set theory arguments and a separability argument, this has cardinality $\beth_1$. This is encouraging towards a positive answer to your second question.

Comment: @Ian I can follow your general ideas but I haven't had formal set theory so I don't know what $\beth_1$ is. But if you think going through cardinal numbers is the only way to tackle these questions, please go ahead.

Comment: As I said, $\beth_1$ is one of the standard symbols for the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. I don't necessarily think that this will be necessary to answer your question. I just think that this fact probably puts you in good shape for a positive answer to question 2; indeed you might have a positive answer to question 2 among $\Omega$ which have cardinality at most $\beth_1$. Of course it must be at least $\beth_0$ (the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$), for otherwise $\mathcal{F}$ would be too small to accommodate all constant random variables.

Comment: @Ian You're right, I missed your clarification for $\beth_1$. I really like your insights so far!

Answer (score 1):

It matters what your definition is of a probability measure but here is a start and it addresses the situation where $\Omega$ is a subset of the reals.  For the first question.  There is an equivalence between CDFs and probability measures on the space.  As was suggested I will give that correspondance:
     $$\mu([-\infty, x]) = F(x)$$
Then $\mu$ can be fully extended to a measure via the [Caratheodory Extension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem).

Given a probability measure $\mu$ you can appeal to the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem) to show that it has two components wrt to $P$.  The first is an absolutely continuous measure wrt to $P$.  The second is singular.  That means you can write the first in terms of its Radon-Nikodym derivative wrt $P$ and the integral of that function is part of the $F(x)$.  The issue though is that there can be a singular part.  To introduce "functions" that represent them you will need to expand your set to distributions to includes the likes of the dirac mass.  See the [Radon Nikodym Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) for more details.

For the second question.  You can define the measure via it's Radon-Nikodym derivative wrt to Lebesgue measure $P$ by setting $\frac{d\mu}{dP} = \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$ where you have to generalize your of derivative to allow the derivative at points where $F$ is discontinuous to result in dirac masses when you take the derivative (i.e. you need the Distributional derivative).  A simple example of that, say $F(x)$ is 0 for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x>=0$.  Then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is a dirac mass at $0$.

Essentially then for such an $\Omega$ the allowable functions $F$ are those that are measurable, non-decreasing, are $0$ off at $-\infty$ and $1$ at $\infty$.

Comment: I think you should clarify the correspondence between CDFs and probability measures; in particular, is every probability measure given by some CDF? (It is fairly routine to check that the reverse is true.) I think that is the more important aspect of the question. Beyond that there is the question as to whether we can choose $P$ such that all probability measures $\mu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.

Comment: That establishes a correspondence between probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ with CDFs. What is the correspondence between probability measures on other spaces with CDFs? Or are you not using this correspondence?

Comment: Regarding your first point, no, not even Lebesgue measure can handle dirac masses. But regarding your second, yes, I updated the answer to say this is all wrt to $\Omega$ being a subset of the reals.

Comment: I think you are getting somewhat bogged down here. Think of how you would construct $\Omega$ to deal with constant variables. You would just take a singleton and its power set. Now to deal with discrete variables where all probabilities are multiples of $1/N$, take $\Omega$ to have $N$ elements, and use its power set and a uniform distribution. The situation is nastier for general discrete variables, but you can pull a trick: build the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, and then have $X=x_1$ on $(0,p_1)$, $X=x_2$ on $(p_1,p_2)$, etc.

Comment: (Cont.) So all discrete CDFs can be realized by random variables on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. By Radon-Nikodym, so can all (absolutely) continuous CDFs. What about the other CDFs (e.g. the CDF given by the Cantor function)?

Comment: Also, sorry to be criticizing from the sidelines rather than posting an answer myself. I don't immediately see a proof, but I'm fairly sure the answer to the OP's question second is actually yes, and that the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ is a realization of it.

Comment: Feel welcome to answer the question yourself if you think there is a better approach.  I would love to see it.

Comment: I'm definitely saying the second question is yes.  Its the first question that deals with an arbitrary $\Omega$.

Comment: As best I can tell, your idea does not show that the answer to the second question is yes, because if $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $P$ then $\frac{d \mu}{dP}$ is not a random variable. So you have not constructed $\Omega,\mathcal{F},P,X$ such that $F_X$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is $F$.

Comment: Oh if you want to require that a random variable is not a distribution, then no.  However, your answer of $(0,1)$ is a realization isn't correct either because again consider the probability measure $P$ with one outcome $1/2$.  It can't be written as a measurable function wrt to $(0,1)$.  It's a delta mass.

Comment: That's actually backwards from how I was doing the construction, which is why I was opposing the idea of trying to identify $F$ with a probability measure. To clarify, my idea for discrete variables was to define $X$ to be identically equal to $x_i$ on $(p_{i-1},p_i)$ (where $p_0=0$), and then arbitrarily define it at the $p_i$. Then $X$ is indeed a measurable function from $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1)))$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. My problem is that I do not know how to extend this to functions which are continuous but not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: ...Having phrased it like that, I realize now that the construction is the same as how we perform sampling numerically, which explains what should be done, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused by your objection above.  It doesn't matter that $\frac{d\mu}{dP}$ isn't a random variable, it's integral $F$ is.  So my $F$ is the same as the one you were just mentioning - namely step functions.

Comment: I think it would have been helpful if we could have kept the notation consistent, i.e. made it clear that we were seeking out $\Omega,\mathcal{F},P$ such that for any $F$ there exists a random variable $X$ such that $F_X=F$. Switching back and forth between the notations was confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and @Ian for the discussion. Please give me some time to digest.

Answer (score 1):

The "universal probability space" in the sense of your second question is $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),m)$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. The procedure for making the identification is the procedure that is commonly used for numerical sampling of a random variable given its CDF. Specifically, we uniformly choose $p \in [0,1]$, then choose the smallest $x$ such that $F(x) \geq p$. This mapping from $p$ to $x$ is a well defined function of $p$; I will call it $F^+$. (In general $F$ is not bijective, so I should not call it $F^{-1}$.) The result is a random variable, because $F^+$ is a nondecreasing function, hence Borel measurable.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Please give me some time to digest this one as well. I'm at school at the moment and I will look more carefully at this when I get home.